# JNA Invalid memory access when writing to file

Tags: java, windows, jna

For debug reasons I am writing a jna wrapper for a C++ DLL (compiled with gcc and mingw32)

write16Byte.dll

```
void write16Byte(const BYTE* mem) {
  FILE* out = fopen("BSTRvalues.txt", "a+");
  if (out == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
  return;
  }
  for (int i=0; i<16; i++) fprintf(out, "0x%x ", mem[i]);
  fwprintf(out, L"\n");
  fclose(out);
}
```

jna wrapper

```
public interface W16BDll extends com.sun.jna.Library {
  W16BDll INSTANCE = (W16BDll)com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary("write16Byte.dll", W16BDll.class);
  void write16Byte(com.sun.jna.Memory version);
}
```

The call of fprintf resultts in "java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access" because when I remove the fprintf everything works fine (I already read the thread in [JNA Invalid memory access when writing to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272671/jna-invalid-memory-access-when-writing-to-stdout))

Comment: What memory are you passing to the function `write16Bytes` when you call it?

Comment: Memory version = new Memory(18); /* I also tried new Memory(100000) */
version.setWideString(0, "10.0.001");

Comment: Memory version = new Memory(18); /* I also tried new Memory(100000) */  
version.setWideString(0, "10.0.001");`

Comment: `Memory version = new Memory(18); // I also tried new Memory(100000)`  
`version.setWideString(0, "10.0.001"); `

Comment: You should update your question to include your actual Java usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on warnings in your compiler (`-Wall` in gcc), it will tell you that you've mismatched your format string and actual argument.

`"%x"` requires an `int` parameter; you're providing `const BYTE`.  Normally I'd expect this to just produce garbage, but depending on the CPU, arch, and stack layout you can get a range of failures.

You need to cast `mem[i]` to `int` (or use a format compatible with `const BYTE`).

Comment: I compiled the dll with

Comment: I compiled the dll with  
`g++.exe -m32 -Wall -DBUILD_DLL -O2  -c write16Byte.dll -o write16Byte.o`  
-> no warnings or errors.  
Next I called the dll-function write16Byte in a C-programm => no runtime error.  
Anyway, I changed the fprint-call in write16Byte from  
`fprintf(out, "0x%x ", mem[i]);` to  
`fprintf(out, "%c ", mem[i]);`  
=> invalid memory access

Comment: So I tried the following new code:    
first:    
`for (int i=0; i<4; i++) fprintf(out, "%x ", (const unsigned int)mem[i]);`    
second:    
`for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {`    
  `const unsigned int* imem = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int*>(mem);`  
  `fprintf(out, "%x ", imem[i]);`  
`}`  
Both times i got an invalid memory access

Comment: Is your library using the `stdcall` calling convention?  If so, your stack will be incorrect by the time you get to your function, resulting in an invalid value for `mem`.  In that case you need to derive from `StdCallLibrary` rather than `Library`.

Comment: You're omitting some things, any one of which might be important.  Who uses the `BUILD_DLL` macro?  Compiling with g++ will mangle your exported function names without `extern "C"`.

Comment: My dll is using `cdecl` calling conventions.  
`BUILD_DLL` is used as a switch, to decide if `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` is used.

Comment: I dont know, what you want to say me with mangling. I dont get a symbol not defined error.  Anyway, my header file contains `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif`.  A preprocessor command for closing brackets is also included.